# TinyMCE text editor's toolbar location in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, tinymce, toolbar

I am using TinyMCE text editor in Angular project. I have followed all steps in TinyMCE Angular integration quick start guide and used TinyMCE Self-hosted method. So far following these steps went nice and fairly simple text editor pops up in my project as it should. My project uses the version "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^7.0.0"

I am having a problem with toolbar location. I need to set it below the text editor, not above as it is by default. The guide tells me to include *toolbar_location: 'bottom'* in the options. But if I do that I get an error.

HTML template:

```
<editor [init]="DescriptionTextEditor"></editor>
```

Typescript file:

```
export class TextEditorComponent implements OnInit {

public DescriptionTextEditor= {
    base_url: '/tinymce',
    suffix: '.min',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    plugins:
        'link lists'
    ,
    toolbar:
        ' bold italic underline | bullist | link | removeformat',
    toolbar_location: 'bottom'
};

constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
}
```

}

If I save the file as above, I get an error:

Compiled with problems:

> ERROR
>
> src/app/.../description.component.html:9:46 - error TS2322: Type '{
> base_url: string; suffix: string; menubar: boolean; statusbar:
> boolean; plugins: string; toolbar: string; toolbar_location: string;
> }' is not assignable to type 'RawEditorOptions'.   Types of property
> 'toolbar_location' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ToolbarLocation | undefined'.
>
> 9     [init]="DescriptionTextEditor">
> ~~~~
>
> src/app/.../description.component.ts:7:15
> 7  templateUrl: './description.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component DescriptionComponent.

If I remove *toolbar_location: 'bottom'* remove the options in TS file then text editor works fine. Only adding this feature breaks it.